# Volume of the solid bounded by the paraboloid $z = r^2$

Tags: calculus, integration, polar-coordinates

To find the volume of the solid bounded by the paraboloid $z = r^2$ and the plane $z = 9$ using cylindrical coordinates.

So here the limits are $0 \le r \le 3$ and $0 \le \theta \le 2\pi$. Hence the volume is
$$V = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^3 r^3 dr d\theta = \frac{81\pi}{2} .$$

Is the solution correct?

Comment: No, the Jacobian is missing.

Comment: @NinadMunshi thank you for pointing out. is it now correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we are measuring the height between $z=9$ and $z=r^2$ and not $z=r^2$ and the $xy$ plane, the integral is$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^3(9-r^2)r~dr~d\theta = \frac{81\pi}{2} .$$